# When can -[NSObject valueForKey:] not return a NSObject?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsobject

In Swift, `valueForKey:` on `NSObject` is defined as `func value(forKey key: String) -> Any?`.

Are there really cases where it won't return an `NSObject?` and if yes, what are these cases?

Comment: Almost all Cocoa classes inherit from `NSObject`, so the return type can be any subclass of `NSObject`

Comment: For non-class return types (like structs), see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/DataTypes.html

Comment: @AndreasOetjen so basically it will pack/unpack NSNumbers and such whenever possible?